# Why does cur_data() within summarize() return df_slice() error?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I ran into trouble today when using `cur_data()` within `summarize()`.

Example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(id = 1:6,
              type = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
              value = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 7, NA))
```

This first pipeline throws an error, mentioning `df_slice()`:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(value),
            n = length(cur_data() %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% pull(id) %>% unique()),
            .groups = "drop")
#> Error in `summarize()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `n = length(...)`.
#> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: type = 1.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! Internal error in `df_slice()`: Columns must match the data frame size.
```

However, switching the order of the summary stats within `summarize()` avoids the error:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarize(n = length(cur_data() %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% pull(id) %>% unique()),
            mean = mean(value),
            .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>    type     n  mean
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     3
#> 2     2     2     7
#> 3     3     1    NA
```

Additionally, piping `cur_data()` into `as.data.frame()` also avoids the error:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(value),
            n = length(cur_data() %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% pull(id) %>% unique()),
            .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>    type  mean     n
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     3     2
#> 2     2     7     2
#> 3     3    NA     1
Created on 2022-02-15 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Why can I not use the first example syntax? Ultimately I calculated anything that required `cur_data()` within `mutate()` and just kept the `first()` observation within a later `summarize()` call, but I'd like to know what I'm missing about `summarize()`.

Additional session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.2/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reprex_2.0.1         palmerpenguins_0.1.0 forcats_0.5.1        stringr_1.4.0        readr_2.1.2         
 [6] tibble_3.1.6         ggplot2_3.3.5        tidyverse_1.3.1      tidyr_1.2.0          purrr_0.3.4         
[11] dplyr_1.0.8
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but another option is: `n = length(unique(id[!is.na(value)]))`.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in dplyr: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open issue with dplyr: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6138

To paraphrase the discussion in the GitHub issue: The problem is caused by
`cur_data()` including the previously summarised column (in this case, `mean`),
without it having been recycled to match the number of rows in the data frame.
That makes `cur_data()` essentially a malfromed data frame.

In your case, using `as.data.frame()` solves the problem because it does
the recycling to make `mean` match the rest of the columns in length, and
having the statements in a different order solves the problem because at
that point `cur_data()` doesn’t include any new columns yet.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dat <- tibble(
  id = 1:6,
  type = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  value = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 7, NA)
)

dat %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarize(
    mean = mean(value),
    str(cur_data())
  )
#> tibble [2 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ id   : int [1:2] 1 2
#>  $ value: num [1:2] 2 4
#>  $ mean : num 3
#> tibble [2 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ id   : int [1:2] 3 4
#>  $ value: num [1:2] 6 8
#>  $ mean : num 7
#> tibble [2 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ id   : int [1:2] 5 6
#>  $ value: num [1:2] 7 NA
#>  $ mean : num NA
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    type  mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     3
#> 2     2     7
#> 3     3    NA
```